# Necessary import for "ProjectType" in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying out Projen and ran into an error on step 4 which requires several config items. It also tells me to "add necessary imports in the config file when applying the projen settings, e.g. for using ProjectType"
https://github.com/seeebiii/projen-test

When I run `npx projen` I get the following error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
...
.projenrc.ts:11:16 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ProjectType'.
11   projectType: ProjectType.LIB,
...
Synthesis failed: Task "default" failed when executing "ts-node --project tsconfig.dev.json .projenrc.ts" ...
```

Comment: You should raise issue in the github repo, although my best guess is you are following the instruction wrongly if not its incorrect or missing details, its either of those two/